# Sum scores from two tables in MySQL using two fields in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: the two tables with sample data and my desired outcome]I have two tables in MySQL. I will call them **grade7** and **grade8**. Both tables have all these fields, *StudentID*, *FirstName*, *LastName*,  *Total_Score*, *mathScore* and *scienceScore*.  In both tables are Student names, but the *StudentIDs* in **grade7** are not the same as those in **grade8**, although the *FirstName* and *LastName* are uniform ( of the same person). What I am trying to do is sum up the scores from **grade7** and **grade8** of the same student. Meaning, sum up the scores of a record with *FirstName* and *LastName* in **grade7** which are equal to *FirstName* and *LastName* in **grade8**. My code below works initially when there are no scores. But if there are scores already there, it seems to add extra scores than what is supposed to be added. Say if it supposed to output 70 as *Total_Score*, it will add another 10 points and output 80. Please look at my code and advise what I should do. Thank you.

```
update grade8 o inner join
(
SELECT op.StudentID
sum(ot.Total_Score) as Total_Score_ot
sum(ot.Maths) as Maths_ot
sum(op.Total_Score) as Total_Score_op
sum(op.Maths) as Maths_op
FROM grade7 ot inner join grade8 op
WHERE  ot.FirstName = op.FirstName AND ot.LastName = op.LastName
GROUP BY op.FirstName
) as o1
SET Total_Score=Total_Score_op + Total_Score_ot
Maths=Maths_op + Maths_ot
```

Comment: Not sure of your exact problem but if you have names in one grade but not in another it won't work. A `union` might be more appropriate

Comment: Apologies if I did not make my question clear. All the fields in both tables are uniform. So I do have FirtsName in both grade8 and grade7

Comment: Please add sample data for all tables, both before _and_ after the update.

Comment: Kindly refer to the image i have just uploaded. With the original question. It shows the grade7 table with sample data, and grade8 table with sample data before and after the update. I hope that is clear for you to understand. Thank you.

Comment: The idea that two students couldn't have the same name seems hopelessly optimistic

Comment: Do you have multiple rows for each student in the tables?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting off with a union of the two tables, then aggregating by student.  Also, I don't know why you seem to be doing an update here rather than a select.

```sql
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SUM(Total_Score) AS Total_Score, SUM(Maths) AS Maths
FROM
(
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Total_Score, Maths FROM grade7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Total_Score, Maths FROM grade8
) t
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I forgot to mention that the result will be added to grade8 table. That is why i have the update grade8 there.

Comment: I don't support doing this.  If you want to view a sum of two tables, use the select I gave above, don't update.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But in this case, I actually need to place the result in the grade8 table. So that I can display the result of this query in a NetBeans GUI. So that the Total_Score and Maths in grade8 will display the result of the query. How do I achieve that? I need help please. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You need to think beyond your UI..  Select is more robust.  You had better be damned sure you only run it once if you're going to update the table!

Comment: Appreciate your comment. I also need help on how to embed SQL SELECT in java so that the result is displayed in my GUI. I ran the query in PHPMyAdmin and it worked fine. Now i need to embed it in java to show the result in the UI.

Comment: @eagle That follow up might work better in a new question.  What you asked above has nothing to do with Java.  Though, I will tell you that your select doesn't require anything special, and it should be fairly easy for you to handle this from Java.

Comment: I don't see how this can work- the student ids are different